# ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. ") error when trying to set up Django

Tags: python, sql, django, heroku, celery

Attempting to follow the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) to set up a Django instance on Heroku.

Got as far as the installation of Celery, up to the following step:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

when I get the following error:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly
>   configured. "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
>   value. Check settings documentation for more details.

I believe that I have my `settings.py` file in the right place `(project-name/project-name)`, and I'm running django 1.4.3, but when I try to run `manage.py diffsettings`, I get the following output:

> BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'  ### DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE':
>   'django.db.backends.dummy', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': '',
>   'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None,
>   'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': '',
>   'OPTIONS': {}}}

Absolutely no idea where the `django.db.backends.dummy` entry comes from, my `settings.py` has  `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`, which I assume is the correct entry even though the Heroku instructions don't tell you to update it at any point.

Any thoughts what I need to edit here?

Comment: where is your settings codes?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue. In the Heroku docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#prerequisites, it says to add the following to `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

You can pass in a parameter of:

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname')
```

And that will allow you to develop locally and on Heroku. The part that actually SOLVES the problem I had though was that the Heroku config environment variable of DATABASE_URL was not actually set. To set this, I ran

```
$ heroku config
```

I saw the Database URL assigned to a separate config variable. So I created a new variable:

```
$ heroko config:add DATABASE_URL={#the database url}
```

That solved my problem. I hope it helps anyone else with similar issues.

Comment: How do I determine the "dbname" in what you posted?

Comment: You can get database url under [https://postgres.heroku.com/databases](https://postgres.heroku.com/databases) -> your_database -> URL _show_ , then you can use that url as default. Make sure to run `python manage.py migrate` before further database action

Answer (score 7):

Try add these lines after your DATABASE setting in your settings.py

```
# Your Database setting. 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
# Add these two lines.
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite://db/sqlite3.db')
```

Comment: actually this is close, I had `#import dj_database_url / #DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()` in my settings file as well as a `setup_loader()` call to djcelery. Commenting out those two lines now gives me a `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.` error.

Comment: Great! Did you know that adding default arg in dj_url_config() makes your setting available on your local environment? This way you dont have to bother with db setting again. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Chatri as you suggested adding the default='sqlite://db/sqlite3.db' fixed the issue.

Comment: I am glad it did help you Shashank. Happy coding!